# is it possible to replace excel with oracle in XLLOOP?

Tags: excel, oracle

in XLLoop we have tow main components:

```
An Excel addin implementation (XLL written in c++).
A server and framework written in java (and in many other languages - see languages section).
```

i want to know is any way to replace excel with oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting effort.
Oracle Database can run java code (except the free Oracle XE versions).
To access the functionserver, which seems to be available as a service over http, 
you can use the utl_http package from PL/SQL even if you run Oracle XE.